# Hide/Show LinearLayout on RecyclerView scrolling

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview, scroll

I want to hide a layout id recycler view is scrolled up and show if it's scroll down. My activity has no Action Bar and I am using a LinearLayout as a custom action bar (with activity name + custom back button  + one custom option button) and a RecyclerView.
I came up with two problems:

1. I can use onScrollListener(), but that has an effect on the animation if I set visibility GONE.
2. I have read a few of the Coordinator Layout but that uses a Toolbar, I don't know if I can implement my layout into the Toolbar as my buttons have functions. Please let me know if I have an option to do that.

It would be really helpful if someone could suggest any solution or any idea how to implement
[image]

Comment: try scroll listener of recycler view

Comment: can we add animation to the show and hide while using scroll listener